# How to scale a windows universal desktop app programatically

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

The default scale factor in desktop is 1 but I want to apply an scale factor of 1.75 to a desktop application. I don´t mean the app bounds (that´s easy) but the scale applied to all visual elements, like mobile version does on devices.

Is there any way to achieve this globally?

Comment: For a XAML app, you could just apply a transform on the root. You can check the code from [this Silverlight sample](http://aka.ms/wpsllarge) and convert it to UWP.

Comment: What about FlexBox ?